Error message in when running functions from ggside package
I am getting an error when I run the ggside package with any plot. This is from the package vignette (so it should work)
i2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species2 = rep(c("A","B"), 75))
p <- ggplot(i2, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- p + geom_xsidedensity(aes(y = after_stat(density))) +
  geom_ysidedensity(aes(x = after_stat(density))) +
  theme_bw() 

p2

Returns the error.
Error in `geom_xsidedensity()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `scales_add_defaults()`:
! could not find function "scales_add_defaults"

Has anyone encountered this and knows what to do?

Suspect the missing function is in the scales package. It’s supposed to be imported https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggside/index.html but maybe you didn’t install the dependencies when you installed ‘ggside’.

Ensure you have both ggplot2 and ggside
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("ggside")

Ensure you have the scales package:
install.packages("scales")

Then, try running the vignette code again. Hope it works!
